# Fft in real time - AsioOut+SampleAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I am currently working on my thesis project, this is an application that writes tablature by ASIO drivers. In short, write what you play. I'm new in all regards Naudio and I'm having poblemas to transform sound into FFT. I am capturing the sound with a device called "GuitarLink" which runs through ASIO4ALL.
So I need to compare frequencies for the chord in real time.

Currently, the program gives me two values, X and Y.
(I am using "SampleAggregator" Class and AsioOut)

MAIN

```
private SampleAggregator sampleAggregator = new(fftLength);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
     
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(SoClose);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
   
void SoClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (PBass)
        {
            sampleAggregator.PerformFFT = true;
            sampleAggregator.FftCalculated += new EventHandler<FftEventArgs>(FftCalculated);

            AsioOut asioOut = new();
            BufferedWaveProvider wavprov = new(new WaveFormat(48000, 1));
            asioOut.AudioAvailable += new EventHandler<AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs>(asio_DataAvailable);
            asioOut.InitRecordAndPlayback(wavprov, 1, 25);
            asioOut.Play();

            I1E.Text = frecuencia.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error de bajo presupuesto", "Obviamente algo anda mal");
    }
}

private void FftCalculated(object sender, FftEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Length; ++i)
    {
        A = e.Result[i].X;
        B = e.Result[i].Y;
        frecuencia = B;
                         
        Debug.WriteLine($"FFT: X={e.Result[i].X} Y={e.Result[i].Y}");
    }
}
  
void asio_DataAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[e.SamplesPerBuffer * 4];

    for (int i = 0; i < e.InputBuffers.Length; i++)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(e.InputBuffers[i], buf, 0, e.SamplesPerBuffer * 4);
        Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, e.OutputBuffers[i], e.SamplesPerBuffer * 4);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i = i + 4)
    {
        float sample = Convert.ToSingle(buf[i] + buf[i + 1] + buf[i + 2] + buf[i + 3]);
        sampleAggregator.Add(sample);
    }

    e.WrittenToOutputBuffers = true;
}
```

SampleAggregator class

```
public class SampleAggregator
{
    // FFT
    public event EventHandler<FftEventArgs> FftCalculated;
    public bool PerformFFT { get; set; }

    // This Complex is NAudio's own! 
    private Complex[] fftBuffer;
    private FftEventArgs fftArgs;
    private int fftPos;
    private int fftLength;
    private int m;

    public SampleAggregator(int fftLength)
    {
        if (!IsPowerOfTwo(fftLength))
            throw new ArgumentException("FFT Length must be a power of two");

        this.m = (int)Math.Log(fftLength, 2.0);
        this.fftLength = fftLength;
        this.fftBuffer = new Complex[fftLength];
        this.fftArgs = new FftEventArgs(fftBuffer);
    }

    public void Add(float value)
    {
        if (PerformFFT && FftCalculated != null)
        {
            fftBuffer[fftPos].X = (float)(value * FastFourierTransform.HammingWindow(fftPos, fftLength));
            fftBuffer[fftPos].Y = 0; // This is always zero with audio.
            fftPos++;
            if (fftPos >= fftLength)
            {
                fftPos = 0;
                FastFourierTransform.FFT(true, m, fftBuffer);
                FftCalculated(this, fftArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    static bool IsPowerOfTwo(int x) => (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
}

public class FftEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Complex[] Result { get; private set; }
    public string resultado = "";

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public FftEventArgs(Complex[] result) => Result = result;
   
    void FftCalculated(object sender, FftEventArgs e)
    {         
    }
}
```

Well the problem is that when I play a note, the values that are delivered are not affected.